# Characterizing quadratic number fields that are subfields of cyclic quartic number fields

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Given a quadratic number field $F = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$, is there a way to determine whether or not $F \subset K$ for some quartic numberfield $K$ with $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$?

Moreover, how can we find that field $K$ if it exists?

For instance, $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is not contained in any cyclic quartic number field and neither is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$.  I thought I heard somewhere that the intermediate subfield of a cyclic quartic number field must be totally real, but I am not sure.

Comment: That sounds reasonable - if not $K$ is not totally real, then Gal($L/K$) must contain complex conjugation, which is of order 2.

Comment: Note that $Aut(F/\mathbb{Q}) \subset Aut(K/\mathbb{Q})$.  If $F$ *were* totally real, then there would be two automorphisms of order $2$.  Namely, $\phi \in Aut(F/\mathbb{Q})$ such that $\phi(\sqrt{d}) = -\sqrt{d}$, and another from complex conjugation.  However, $\mathbb{Z}_4$ has only one element of order $2$.  The moral of the story is that $\sqrt{d} \in \mathbb{C}$ \ $\mathbb{R}$ if this is to work.